# Automatic reduction and cancellation of units with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, equation, units-of-measurement

I am having issues with getting units to cleanly simplify. The program I am writing is involved with the calculation of spring properties, requiring 10/11 user controlled variables and about a dozen equations, all of which deal with mixed sets of units. The one missing variable can be any of the non-material properties (1/5), so I am trying to use symbolic equations that can solve for whatever my one missing variable is. I tried setting the variables with pint, which could reduce properly and did not have this problem, but they could not Sympify properly, so I had to switch back to SymPy's unit system.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
from sympy.physics.units import *
from sympy import pi, sqrt, N, Eq, symbols, solve

lbf=Quantity('lbf', abbrev='lbf')
lbf.set_global_relative_scale_factor((convert_to(pound*acceleration_due_to_gravity,newton))/newton, newton)

F, Y, L, A, m, ns, xi, d = symbols('F Y L A m ns xi d')
ssy, alpha, beta, C = symbols('ssy alpha beta C')

F= 20*lbf
Y= 2*inch
L= 3.25*inch
d= .08*inch

m= .145
A= 201.00
A*=kilo*psi*inch**m
ns= 1.20
xi= .15

eqSsy=Eq(ssy,.45*A/(d**m))
ssy=solve(eqSsy)[0]
eqAlpha=Eq(alpha,eqSsy.rhs/ns)
alpha=solve(eqAlpha)[0]
eqBeta=Eq(beta,(8*(1+xi)*F)/(N(pi)*(d**2)))
beta=solve(eqBeta)[0]
eqC=Eq(C,((2*eqAlpha.rhs-eqBeta.rhs)/(4*eqBeta.rhs))+sqrt((((2*eqAlpha.rhs-eqBeta.rhs)/(4*eqBeta.rhs))**2)-(3*eqAlpha.rhs)/(4*eqBeta.rhs)))
C=solve(eqC)[0]
print(ssy, '\n', alpha, '\n', beta, '\n', C)
```

This issue is not related to the lbf unit I had to create, it still happened when I had it using the raw units before I cleaned it up. This leads to `C` coming out as `1.62e-28*(3.66645442100299e+28*inch**2*psi - 1.54320987654321e+27*lbf + 3.666454421003e+28*sqrt(-0.252539870841386*inch**2*lbf*psi + (inch**2*psi - 0.0420899784735643*lbf)**2))/lbf` instead of `10.5334875999498`, because none of the units are cancelled through the calculation process.

The "fix" to this problem that I want to avoid is changing line 27, the creation of `eqBeta`, I have to hard convert the output units to be in `psi` to prevent the units from coming out as `lbf/inch**2` instead of the pressure unit.

```
eqBeta=Eq(beta,convert_to((8*(1+xi)*F)/(N(pi)*(d**2)),psi))
```

Is there any way I can make `beta` automatically reduce to the appropriate pressure unit? The input values are given through a PyQt5 program, not like in this demo, and they can be given either imperial or metric units, so I don't want to be manually forcing a conversion into `psi` (or forcibly converting `C` into being unitless).

I would also appreciate if someone knew of a cleaner or better way to do these calculations, as I have just been bashing my head against SymPy because I haven't found another solution. These equations and variable names are taken from a machine design textbook, and I don't want to have to manually create a step-by-step solving process for each possible missing variable.

Comment: Which version of SymPy are you using? I'm using 1.11.1 and I get the correct output

Comment: @Davide_sd I also am using Sympy 1.11.1 and Python 3.9, due to PyQT issues. Did you remove the unit conversion, or run the code as it is? The problematic behavior is specifically seen when I change `eqBeta=Eq(beta,convert_to((8*(1+xi)*F)/(N(pi)*(d**2)),psi))` to `eqBeta=Eq(beta,(8*(1+xi)*F)/(N(pi)*(d**2)))`. The code I uploaded contained the "bad solution" that I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try listing the base units as the quantities to be reduced to:

```py
>>> convert_to(C, [kg, meter, second]).n(2)
11.0
```

Or if you don't know which ones to use,

```py
>>> from sympy.physics.units import UnitSystem
>>> sibase = UnitSystem.get_unit_system("SI")._base_units
>>> convert_to(C, sibase).n(2)
11.0
```

cf [this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23022)

Comment: Thanks! I had previously tried accessing the base units to use it like this, and making my "automatic" reduction be a forcible base unit simplification within each equation, but ran into an error where it wouldn't let me access it. The error still shows up in the linter, but at least with assigning it to `sibase` it lets me use it. This doesn't solve all my woes with the system, but at least I think I can make it generally work.